# Why does the text in console disappear on click?

Tags: c++, console

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
WORD setting1 = FOREGROUND_RED; // these are the user settings
WORD setting2 = FOREGROUND_RED;
WORD setting3 = FOREGROUND_RED;

WORD green = FOREGROUND_GREEN; // the 2 colors the settings can change from
WORD red = FOREGROUND_RED;

int changecolor(int key) //find out what the user pressed and then changed the color of the setting
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case VK_F1:
        if (setting1 == red)
        {
            setting1 = green;
        }
        else
            setting1 = red;
    case VK_F2:
        if (setting2 == red)
        {
            setting2 = green;
        }
    case VK_F3:
        if (setting3 = red)
        {
            setting3 = green;
        }
    }
}

WORD getconsoletextattributes(HANDLE hcon)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bufinfo; // setting a screen buffer variable
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hcon, &bufinfo); // getting the console screen buffer and putting it into the bufinfo
    return bufinfo.wAttributes;
}

WORD setcolor(HANDLE hcon, WORD color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hcon,color);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    const int getcolors = getconsoletextattributes(hcon);

    while(true)
    {
        int key;
        for(key = 8; key < 190; key++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(key))
            {
                changecolor(key);
            }
        }
        setcolor(hcon,setting1);
        cout << "Setting1 \n\n\n" << endl;
        setcolor(hcon,setting2);
        cout << "Setting2 \n\n\n" << endl;
        setcolor(hcon,setting3);
        cout << "Setting3 \n\n\n" << endl;

        Sleep(20);
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

I'm running Windows 10, using the codeblocks IDE with the GNU compiler.

I'm not used to the codeblocks IDE, but it's kind of small and my laptop doesn't have that much space.
So I'm trying to make a hack menu type thing, and what is supposed to happen is: it prints off some settings and when you push down F1-F3 it toggles the color from red to green (saying if the hack is on or off).

It works like its supposed to, but whenever I click on the console, my texts disappears. The only way it comes back, is if I re-build the program.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Hard to say, but I would start by not calling `system("cls")` every 20 milliseconds.  Why not only clear and redraw the menu when one of your settings changes?

Comment: `changecolor` and `setcolor` both do not return a value. You might want to fix that first.

Comment: that might work but i need to constantly wait until the the getasynckeystate() gets a key

Comment: Yes of course, so you can poll that every 20ms, but there is no need to draw the menu every time around the loop.

Comment: There's no need to redraw everything, once is enough, then you can wait for a key. @burn145

Comment: hm ok i will try to have a while loop around the get key part and then when it gets a key it will break and change the key. thanks